# Calculate the biggest consecutive sessions chunk in a file MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, ranking

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
    respondent_id   day_session daydiff
nmo876  11/19/2017  0
nmo876  11/20/2017  1
nmo876  11/21/2017  1
nmo876  11/23/2017  2
nmo876  11/24/2017  1
nmo876  11/25/2017  1
nmo876  11/26/2017  1
nmo876  11/27/2017  1
nmo876  11/28/2017  1
nmo876  11/29/2017  1
nmo876  11/30/2017  1
nmo876  12/1/2017   1
nmo876  12/2/2017   1
nmo876  12/3/2017   1
nmo876  12/4/2017   1
nmo876  12/5/2017   1
nmo876  12/6/2017   1
nmo876  12/7/2017   1
nmo876  12/8/2017   1
nmo876  12/9/2017   1
nmo876  12/10/2017  1
nmo876  12/11/2017  1
nmo876  12/12/2017  1
nmo876  12/13/2017  1
nmo876  12/14/2017  1
nmo876  12/15/2017  1
nmo876  12/16/2017  1
nmo876  12/17/2017  1
nmo876  12/18/2017  1
nmo876  12/19/2017  1
nmo876  12/20/2017  1
nmo876  12/23/2017  3
nmo876  12/24/2017  1
nmo876  12/26/2017  2
nmo876  12/27/2017  1
nmo876  12/28/2017  1
nmo876  12/29/2017  1
nmo876  12/30/2017  1
nmo876  12/31/2017  1
nmo876  1/2/2018    2
nmo876  1/3/2018    1
nmo876  1/4/2018    1
nmo876  1/5/2018    1
```

I want to write a script that chooses the largest chunk of consecutive day_sessions from a dataset where a user might have multiple consecutive day_sessions, i.e. where daydiff = 1. For nmo876 the output would be 27.

Here is more data for which the code should calculate the largest chunk of consecutive daily sessions:

```
jkl567  11/19/2017  1
jkl567  11/20/2017  1
jkl567  11/21/2017  1
jkl567  11/22/2017  1
jkl567  11/23/2017  1
jkl567  11/24/2017  1
jkl567  11/25/2017  1
jkl567  11/26/2017  1
jkl567  11/27/2017  1
jkl567  11/28/2017  1
jkl567  11/29/2017  1
jkl567  11/30/2017  1
jkl567  12/1/2017   1
jkl567  12/2/2017   1
jkl567  12/3/2017   1
jkl567  12/4/2017   1
jkl567  12/5/2017   1
jkl567  12/6/2017   1
jkl567  12/7/2017   1
jkl567  12/8/2017   1
jkl567  12/9/2017   1
jkl567  12/10/2017  1
jkl567  12/11/2017  1
jkl567  12/12/2017  1
jkl567  12/13/2017  1
jkl567  12/14/2017  1
jkl567  12/15/2017  1
jkl567  12/16/2017  1
jkl567  12/17/2017  1
jkl567  12/18/2017  1
jkl567  12/19/2017  1
jkl567  12/20/2017  1
jkl567  12/21/2017  1
jkl567  12/22/2017  1
jkl567  12/23/2017  1
jkl567  12/24/2017  1
jkl567  12/25/2017  1
jkl567  12/26/2017  2
jkl567  12/28/2017  1
jkl567  12/29/2017  3
jkl567  1/1/2018    1
jkl567  1/2/2018    1
jkl567  1/3/2018    1
jkl567  1/4/2018    1
```

Comment: From 11/24/17 until 12/20/17 = 27 days.

Comment: Didn't I answer this here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49437698/1930331

Comment: No, that script would add up all day sessions that are a day apart from each other. It wouldn't calculate the largest chunk of such sessions - for example, if a user had gone online from 12/1/17 until 12/8/17, stopped for two days and then gone online 12/10/17 until 12/25/17, the first script would return 20. This question requests an output of 14, i.e. grabbing only the second chunk of consecutive sessions.

Comment: OK probably needs a `group by` component as well but I stick with the premise

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by using variables.

```
select respondent_id, max(counter) from (
select respondent_id, day_session, 
 if(daydiff = 1, @counter := @counter + 1, @counter := 0) counter 
 from mydata 
 join (select @counter := 0) d
 order by respondent_id, day_session
) a 
group by respondent_id
```

***Explanation***

Inner query prepares a result with an additional column as counter which increments only if the daydiff is one.

Outer query then consolidates the result and show the highest value.

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bc8fdd/1)

Comment: Can this be done without imperative programming? It's SQL so the performance might be considerably worse when using variables etc.

Comment: Other than the above mentioned aproach, all I can think of is writing a Stored Procedure which uses a cursor to iterate and then do the calculations.

Comment: Same problem. See the solution I posted to similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49437698/1930331.

Comment: @isaach1000 Also, I have seen the other answer you have posted in the different question (posted by the same user though). I do not think that will work with the sample data provided in this question. For e.g. "nmo876  12/23/2017  3" creates a gap in the series, hence the counter should stop here

Comment: That's exactly the idea. OP wants longest consecutive daily sessions.

Comment: @Akhil when I run your above script it gives me incorrect, far-too-large outputs for some users, such as jkl567, whose data I posted above. Running your script for this user I got an output of 109 (far larger than even the count of day_sessions this user has recorded). The output should be 37.

Comment: @dataelephant please create a SQL fiddle with sample input.i shall check why the result is incorrect